# How to check if some recurring text is missing in a text file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
{
     "mimeType": "web",
     "body": "adsfdf",
     "data_source_name": "abc",
     "format": "web",
     "url": "http://google.com/",
     "urls": "http://google.com/",
     "lastModified": "123123",
     "title": "Google",
     "docdatetime_dt": "1231234",
     "wfbdomain": "google.com",
     "id": "http://google.com",
     },
     {
     "mimeType": "web",
     "body": "adsfdf",
     "data_source_name": "zdf",
     "format": "web",
     "url": "http://facebook.com/",
     "urls": "http://facebook.com/",
     "lastModified": "123123",
     "title": "Facebook",
     "docdatetime_dt": "1231234",
     "wfbdomain": "facebook.com",
     "id": "http://facebook.com",
     },
    {
     "mimeType": "web",
     "body": "adsfdf",
     "format": "web",
     "url": "http://twitter.com/",
     "urls": "http://twitter.com/",
     "lastModified": "123123",
     "title": "Twitter",
     "docdatetime_dt": "1231234",
     "wfbdomain": "twitter.com",
     "id": "http://twitter.com",
     }
```

If you see the third one in the above block, you will notice that **"data_source_name": ....** is missing. I have a file that is really huge and want to check if this particular thing is missing, and if missing, print/echo it.

I tried sed but am unable to figure out how to use it properly.

Is it possible using sed or something else?

Comment: I assume you mean "if it is missing from a particular block enclosed by curly braces".

Comment: Try `gawk -v RS='}\\s*,\\s*{' '!/"data_source_name":/'`

Comment: This seems to be a JSON file. Why not use a JSON schema validator?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, note that it's invalid json because of those spurious trailing `,` in each record.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could use `}, {` as the record separator and print the records that don't contain `"data_source_name":`:

```
gawk -v RS='}\\s*,\\s*{' '!/"data_source_name":/'
```

Or you could decode it as the kind of json it seems to be using for instance `JSON::PP`:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -l -0777 -ne '
  $j = JSON::PP->new->relaxed->pretty;
  print $j->encode($_) for grep {!defined($_->{data_source_name})}
                           @{$j->decode("[$_]")}' < file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `awk` seems more reasonable to use in this case, you could use gnu `sed` as:

```
sed 'H;/}/{g;/data_source_name/!p;z;h};d'
```

description:

```
    #!/bin/sed -f

    H                       # append each line to hold space
    /}/ {                   # on each closing bracket
      g                     # get contents of hold space to pattern space
      /data_source_name/!p  # print pattern space if it does not contain "data_source_name"
      z;h                   # empty hold space
    }
    d
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is a valid JSON array of objects,

```bsh
$ jq '.[] | select(has("data_source_name")|not)' file
{
  "mimeType": "web",
  "body": "adsfdf",
  "format": "web",
  "url": "http://twitter.com/",
  "urls": "http://twitter.com/",
  "lastModified": "123123",
  "title": "Twitter",
  "docdatetime_dt": "1231234",
  "wfbdomain": "twitter.com",
  "id": "http://twitter.com"
}
```

This uses the command-line parser `jq` to output all objects that do not have a `data_source_name` key.

What makes your data invalid JSON (because I think you have modified it for the question) is that it is missing the surrounding `[ ... ]` and that it has trailing commas at the end of  the last value in each object, before each terminating `}`.

If your JSON input was a *set* of objects (no surrounding `[ ... ]` and no comma between them, and no trailing comma before each terminating `}`), then using just the `select()` statement in the expression would work.  I.e., you would remove `.[]`, which is only used for extracting the objects out of the array.